# Посоветуйте модули для работы с формулами

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, поиск-библиотек

Нужны модули для работы с формулами (раскрытие скобок,умножение скобок, пр.), математикой (элементарной и высшей). Что посоветуете?

Comment: [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ссылки с подробным объяснением и примерами кода разных библиотек.

Matplotlib - http://matplotlib.org/index.html

NumPy - http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial

Dislin - http://www2.mps.mpg.de/dislin/exa_python.html

Comment: Сасибо за ответ. Вы можете привести ссылки на них и будет здорово, если Вы приведете примеры использования.

Comment: Без проблем, вот, держите Matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/index.html ; NumPy: http://cs231n.github.io/python-numpy-tutorial/ ; Dislin: https://www2.mps.mpg.de/dislin/exa_python.html  - все руководства содержат полный набор готовых решений и множество примеров, которые можно использовать в качестве шаблона под свои задачи, а так же рассказано что из себя в принципе представляет модуль.

Comment: в теле ответа, пожалуйста. Я как бы не для себя прошу(мне оно не нужно). Просто хочется чтобы Ваш ответ кому-то помог впоследствии.  А комментарии читают не все. Вы можете пройти в раздел справки и почитать, как желательно оформлять вопросы/ответы, чтобы они впоследствии кому-то помогли

Answer (score 3):

Примеры использования модуля [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html):

```
In [33]: from sympy import *

In [34]: x, y = symbols('x y')

In [35]: formula = '(x**2 + 3*y + 16) * (5*x - 2*y**2 -1) * (1 + x**3)'

In [36]: expand(formula)
Out[36]: 5*x**6 - 2*x**5*y**2 - x**5 + 15*x**4*y + 80*x**4 - 6*x**3*y**3 - 32*x**3*y**2 - 3*x**3*y - 11*x**3 - 2*x**2*y**2 - x**2 + 15*x*y + 80*x - 6*y**3 - 32*y**2 - 3*y - 16

In [37]: simplify(formula)
Out[37]: -(x**3 + 1)*(-5*x + 2*y**2 + 1)*(x**2 + 3*y + 16)
```

---

```
In [49]: factor('16*x**2 + 16*x + 4')
Out[49]: 4*(2*x + 1)**2
```

---

```
In [51]: simplify('sin(x)**2 + cos(x)**2')
Out[51]: 1
```